# Tkinter filedialog is stealing focus and not returning it without "Alt-tab" in Python 3.4.1

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

First question here, but I've answered a few, so hopefully there'll be enough information here for someone to give me a pointer in the right direction.

I have the following code that will form part of an app I'm building. I want users to be able to enter their name and evaluate some images, scoring them using the slider. In order to define the source of the images, I want to select a folder using `filedialog.askdirectory` so the user can verify the correct folder containing the images.

I've stripped out the buttons and the functions that record data to simplify this.

So, the problem I have is that when the window pops up, the filedialog appears and allows me to choose the folder. After I've chosen though, the `Entry` fields are not able to be selected to allow the user to type in their name. If I navigate away from the window by Alt-tab or by clicking another window and going back, I can position the cursor and proceed as normal - obviously, this isn't ideal for my end-users.

Here is the filedialog popup shown here:

[image: <code>filedialog</code> popup]

And the second window, which doesn't automatically take focus:

[image: Second (main application) Window]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy as np

class Model:

    def __init__(self):

        self.scores = []
        self.position = 0
        self.first_name = ""
        self.last_name = ""


class WelcomeWindow:


    def __init__(self, master):

        button_width=25
        button_height=10
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        #self.file_dialog = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.directory = filedialog.askdirectory(parent=self.master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame,
                                height=600,
                                width=800
                               )
        self.model = Model()
        self.first_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.last_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)

        self.slider = tk.Scale(self.frame, 
                               length=button_width * 20,
                               width=button_width * 2,
                               sliderlength=150,
                               showvalue=False,
                               from_=-3.00,
                               to=3.00,
                               orient="horizontal",
                               tickinterval=1,
                               label="Here is a slider",
                               resolution=0.01
                              )
        self.frame.pack()
        self.first_name_entry.pack()
        self.last_name_entry.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.slider.pack()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    win = WelcomeWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

I've tried setting the `takefocus` option for the `frame` and for the `first_name_entry` field to `True` with no success. I've also tried adjusting the parent of `self.directory` to `self.frame` and that completely removes my ability to interact with the main window.

If I've left anything out, please leave a comment and I'll provide anything I can

Comment: Hi Any watchers - I've managed to solve this using `self.frame.focus_force()` but there is a warning on that function to use with caution - any better/different solutions are happily accepted

Comment: Related: [python3 tkinter Entry() cannot select text field until I click outside app window once](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51956545/3714930)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known issues on Windows systems where using filedialog before the mainloop has had a chance to fully loop the first time causing this kind of focus issue.

Originally I solved this kind of issue using `after()` to schedule the filedialog to happen sometime after the first loop has completed but thanks to [fhdrsdg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3714930/fhdrsdg) comment there is a simpler method to fix this using `update_idletasks()`.

Here is your code reworked to fix the focus issue and some general clean up.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.scores = []
        self.position = 0
        self.first_name = ""
        self.last_name = ""


class WelcomeWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        button_width = 25
        button_height = 10
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.directory = ''
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.frame, height=600, width=800)
        self.model = Model()
        self.first_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.last_name_entry = tk.Entry(self.frame)
        self.slider = tk.Scale(self.frame, length=button_width * 20, width=button_width * 2, sliderlength=150, showvalue=False,
                               from_=-3.00, to=3.00, orient="horizontal", tickinterval=1, label="Here is a slider", resolution=0.01)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.first_name_entry.pack()
        self.last_name_entry.pack()
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.slider.pack()
        self.update_idletasks() # adding this here fixes the focus issue
        self.directory = filedialog.askdirectory()


def main():
    WelcomeWindow().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: To add to this, the issue only happens on Windows and calling `update_idletasks()` right before opening the filedialog also does the trick.

Comment: This is great! Thank you and @fhdrsdg for this speedy resolution!

Comment: @fhdrsdg thanks for posting the related question. I have updated my answer on that older post now as well.