# Tkinter filedialog breaks entry widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

tl;dr: When the application calls `tkinter.filedialog`, `entry` fields do not properly focus.

Long explanation:

When initializing a tkinter application, the `entry` fields are enabled by default. Their state is `tk.ENABLED`, they can be focused on by scrolling through fields with `tab`, and, most importantly, they can be clicked on to select the field.

For some reason, this behavior is broken by calling `tkinter.filedialog`. If a method of `tkinter.filedialog` is called, such as `askdirectory` or `askopenfile()`, the `entry` field will still have the `tk.ENABLED` state, and the background will be properly styled, but clicking on the entry field will not insert the cursor or select the field. Typing, of course, does not register.

This can be worked around by toggling to a different window and toggling back. However, the file dialog windows (properly) return the user directly back to the main window, and so users are always presented with a main window that appears to be locked up.

See this example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

BR8K = True

root = tk.Tk()

if BR8K:
    filedialog.askdirectory()

entry = tk.Entry(root, takefocus=True, highlightthickness=2)
entry.grid(sticky="WE")


root.mainloop()
```

Here, the code behaves properly if `BR8K` is `False`, and incorrectly if `BR8K` is `True`.

(Note: In a production environment, this would be object oriented. The issue persists in an object oriented environment.)

Comment: There is a known issue with dialog in tkinter that messes with focus if you are starting the dialog option before the mainloop has had a chance to loop at least once. You can fix this with an `after()` statement or make your dialog an option that is called with a button. This is actually a common problem mentioned here on Stack Overflow often enough.

Comment: Odd, I must not have had the right search terms. The loop part makes sense, but could you briefly expound on how `after()` would be used here?

Comment: @ `after()` is one way to get around this by setting a timer to execute the dialog say after 1/10 of a second giving the mainloop a chance to be reached but the easiest fix is to use `update_idletask()` directly before the dialog window. Here is a related post I have answered in the past: [Tkinter filedialog is stealing focus and not returning it without “Alt-tab” in Python 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53765237/7475225)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter filedialog is stealing focus and not returning it without "Alt-tab" in Python 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763079/tkinter-filedialog-is-stealing-focus-and-not-returning-it-without-alt-tab-in-p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issues resulting from a dialog window being called prior to the mainloop() being reached for the first time.

The simplest way to fix this is to add `update_idletask()` before the dialog.

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

BR8K = True

root = tk.Tk()
# By adding this you avoid the focus breaking issue of calling dialog before the mainloop() has had its first loop.
root.update_idletasks() 

if BR8K:
    filedialog.askdirectory()

entry = tk.Entry(root, takefocus=True, highlightthickness=2)
entry.grid(sticky="WE")


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem, and it solved my issue in the production code as well. Thanks. 

If I may ask, where should I have gone to find the information about the bug? I searched around for a little bit and didn't find anything about this in my usual places.

Comment: Sometimes searching may be difficult if you are not 100% sure what to search for. Because something like this does not produce a traceback error its even harder. I would say try the simplest search terms you could think of. like "Filedialog focus problem".