# Menu issue with Python and Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, visual-studio-code, pyenv, macos-catalina

**Environment: macOS Catalina 10.15, Python 3.7.4 via pyEnv, Tcl/Tk 8.6.9, Visual Studio Code 1.39.2**

I am having an issue with the Python menu not responding to mouse clicks upon startup when I am debugging my code.

After upgrading to Catalina, I performed a fresh install of pyEnv and Tcl/Tk via Homebrew, then I installed Python 3.7.4 through pyEnv.  It's the same setup I have on my other Mac that is running macOS Mojave, but my other Mac is not demonstrating this issue.

Is anyone else experiencing this problem on their Mac with macOS Catalina?

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

When this is run it displays a tk window on my Mac, but the Python menu at the top will not respond to mouse clicks until I CMD+Tab, or click, out of the app and then CMD+Tab, or click, back into it.  After doing one of those two things the menu responds to mouse clicks as it should.  It's acting like Python does not have focus, but it does as far as I can tell.

**EDIT**: The code above is very minimalistic just to demonstrate a point.  However to demonstrate better I added a frame with a button as well as the suggested root.update_idletasks() by @Mike - SMT.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300+15+15")

myFrame = tk.Frame(root)
myFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="nsew")
myButton = tk.Button(myFrame, text="Quit", command=lambda: exit())
myButton.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='ew')

root.update_idletasks()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hum. See this post and let me know if that helps. [Tkinter filedialog is stealing focus and not returning it without “Alt-tab” in Python 3.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53763079/tkinter-filedialog-is-stealing-focus-and-not-returning-it-without-alt-tab-in-p). I feel like it might be related to this here. Maybe `root.update_idletasks()` will help here. I know the issues are not the exact same but it could be focus related as sometimes tkinter has issues when things are done in this minimal form.

Comment: I tried adding it to the above code on my system right before the root.mainloop() and it didn't help.  I put it into my actual program I am writing and it does not work there either.  I also tried this on a clean machine with Catalina and Python 3.8.0 and Tcl/Tk 8.6.9 and the behavior remains the same.

Comment: Python has focus because even if you just click the frame, the appearance does not change (buttons on the window do not change color).  This is really weird and only occurs under Catalina that I can tell.  It's not a big deal to me since the program is only for my use, but it's an annoyance to have to CMD+Tab/Click out of the python window and come back to access my menu.

Comment: Then I am not sure. I do not have a Mac to test

Answer (score 0):

The issue you describe sounds identical to an [upstream issue in Tk](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/tktview?name=bf93d098d7) on macOS Catalina, which I had reported a few months ago, but is still unresolved due to difficulty reproducing the issue and finding a working solution for it.

If you're interested in getting any updates on the issue, or would like to help investigate it, I suggest adding a comment to the ticket.